# Does classical electrodynamics have $U(1)$ symmetry? If yes, how?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, classical-electrodynamics, gauge-invariance

Quantum electrodynamics (QED) is based on $U(1)$ symmetry. What happens to this symmetry in classical electrodynamics?

**Addendum** The books on classical electrodynamics such as J. D. Jackson, does not mention about $U(1)$ symmetry in the context of gauge invariance (as far as I know). Gauge invariance is simply understood, in classical electrodynamics books, as the invariance of Maxwell's equations under $A_\mu\to A_\mu+\partial_\mu\chi(x)$. There is no sign of U(1) invariance that I can discover here. On the other hand, when something like Dirac equation or Dirac field is brought into the scene then the implementation U(1) transformation is clear. But that is always discussed in quantum field theory books. It appears that it is essential to have a Dirac field to understand U(1) symmetry. So the question is whether it is possible to understand the existence of U(1) symmetry in classical electrodynamics without bringing in the Dirac field into the picture?

Comment: Yes, it's the same.

Comment: Why do you think anything about the $\mathrm{U}(1)$ symmetry is quantum? Generally, we obtain a quantum field theory by quantizing a classical one, how do you think new symmetries could appear in this process? (As opposed to disappearing, cf. quantum anomalies)

Comment: I'm guessing your difficulty might be that you've only seen $U(1)$ symmetry derived from a minimal coupling condition with Schrödinger's / Dirac equation (*i.e.* that the EM field gauge conditions can be made to absorb the extra terms that appear in the uncoupled  Schrödinger / Dirac equation when the quantum state $\psi$ is multiplied by an arbitrary phase term $e^{i\,\phi(\mathbb{r})}$)? If this answers @ACuriousMind's rhetorical question, then this tells us the answer you need.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I'm not quite thinking about anomalies. I'm asking how do I convince myself that U(1) invariance is there in classical electrodynamics. In Classical Electrodynamics books such the one by J. D. Jackson there is no mention of $U(1)$ symmetry in the context of gauge invariance (as far as I know). This symmetry is mentioned only in QFT books in the context of gauge invariance. Moreover, in classical electrodynamics, the fields are real fields where as the elements of $U(1)$ are complex, in general.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Yes!

Comment: @ACuriousMind When we talk about gauge invariance in classical electrodynamics we mean the invariance of Maxwell's equations under $A_\mu\to A_\mu+\partial_\mu\chi(x)$. From this, I don't see any sign of U(1) symmetry there. Of course, I may be missing something but I don't know what. Without Dirac field how will the concept of U(1) symmetry be understood here?

Comment: Comment to the title (v3): It seems that OP is not actually asking about classical vs. quantum E&M,  but rather about E&M with or without matter fields. Note that matter fields also exist classically when $\hbar=0$.

Answer (score 18):

1. A free "$\mathrm{U}(1)$" gauge theory can never tell whether the gauge group is $\mathrm{U}(1)$ or $\mathbb{R}$ because the only field in the theory, the gauge potential $A$, transforms as
   $$ A\mapsto A + \partial_\mu \chi,$$ 
   where $\chi$ is just a real-valued function, and the real numbers are the Lie algebra of both $\mathrm{U}(1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$. This is not a classical or quantum property, you simply cannot tell the difference. So, in a sense, asking whether this theory has $\mathrm{U}(1)$ symmetry or not is meaningless - it has $\mathfrak{u}(1)$ symmetry, and there is no meaningful notion of the symmetry *group*.
2. Electromagnetism coupled to an external conserved current still cannot tell what the gauge group is, since the current is gauge-invariant.
3. Electromagnetism coupled to *other fields* can tell what the gauge group is, since part of coupling it to other fields is specifying how these fields transform under gauge transformations. There we have a choice between (infinitesimally) $\psi \mapsto \psi + \chi \psi$ and $\psi\mapsto \psi + \mathrm{i}\chi \psi$, which lead to finite transformations $\psi\mapsto \mathrm{e}^{\chi}\psi$ and $\psi\mapsto \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\chi}\psi$, respectively. The former corresponds to a gauge group $\mathbb{R}$, the latter to $\mathrm{U}(1)$. Again, none of this is classical or quantum.

The reason you likely think that the $\mathrm{U}(1)$ is a quantum feature is that it much more natural in quantum field theory than in classical field theory to have complex-valued fields, but in fact we can consider e.g. classical electromagnetism coupled to a classical complex scalar field and then we are likewise forced to specify the gauge group.

Comment: If I understood it correct, you're saying in point 1 of your answer that a free “U(1)” gauge theory is associated with an unambiguous Lie algebra but no unambiguous Lie group. How are you sure that there is an unambiguous Lie algebra? How does the algebra look like? Thanks. @ACuriousMind

Comment: @SRS $\chi$ is real-valued, so the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{u}(1)$ is simply $\mathbb{R}$ with the trivial Lie bracket.

Comment: Well. By a Lie algebra, I understand the algebra of the generators of a Lie group. If there is no Lie group, what does it mean to have a Lie algebra? @ACuriousMind

Comment: @SRS Come to think of it, I've even heard people talk about "noncompact $U(1)$ gauge symmetry", on this very site even, which does my head in, because clearly(well, maybe!!) they mean $(\mathbb{R},\,+)$- that's an awfully confusing way to talk about things.

Comment: "...thus you see how the gauge transformations compose:..." I think I'm struggling with this. May be because I'm not habituated to think about Lie algebras in this way. All I can understand is that $\chi(x)$ is a real-valued function in classical ED and can live on $\mathbb{R}$. It's not clear in classical ED that $\chi$ is a parameter of some Lie group. @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance

Comment: @SRS A [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) is simply a vector space with a Lie bracket.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance How do I understand that a transformation like $A\to A+\partial_\mu\chi$ has anything to do with a Lie bracket. This transformation is not some exponential (which the Lie group elements are).

Comment: @SRS - Sorry, I am confusing myself a little here, again, owing to the fact that the Lie algebra and group look so much alike by dint of Abelianhood BTW I'm getting this clear myself as a non field theorist. In the $A$ field transformations, you can only see the algebra  -and these compose in this Abelian case just like the group operations, the latter acting on the classical or quantum field $\psi$. You "see" a Lie bracket when you compose group operations, and it will show up in general in the $A$ components through the Campbell Baker Hausdorff theorem. But here, the Lie bracket is trivial -

Comment: - the BCH formula terminates and you don't "see" a Lie bracket at all. Which makes it easy to commit the mistake I just made - *i.e.* forget what the group actually acts on. Since you don't see what the group is acting on in simply Maxwell's equations - only the algebra, you do have to specify the field $\psi$. I think also that most physicists would call the Maxwell-Dirac coupled equations (i.e. the "first quantized", on particle Dirac equation) where minimal coupling is often first discussed a *classical* system, which is possibly adding to confusion here.

Comment: Wouldn't this just make the symmetry group the group of all gradiable functions $\chi : \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ under addition?

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Yes, if you're entirely unburdened by standard gauge theory approaches you might interpret the $\mathfrak{u}(1)$ algebra symmetry as a group (an abelian Lie algebra is a group under addition!). It depends on what you consider "the" symmetry group in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Using compact notation of differential forms, the differential operator $D=d+A$ is a covariant operator with the gauge potential $1$-form $A$. The field $2$-form is $F~=~D\wedge D$ $=~(d~+~A)\wedge(d~+~A)$. This acting on a unit with $d\wedge d~=~0$ (boundary of boundary is 0) gives 
$$
F~=~dA~+~A\wedge A,
$$
The $U(1)$ group simply means that $A\wedge A~=~0$. We of course know that a $1$-form in an exterior product with itself is zero. However, if there are internal color or charge indices you can have a number of these. In $SU(2)$ there are $3$ gauge field and in $SU(3)$ there are $8$. With $U(1)$ there is only one gauge potential with no charge index.

The field $2$-form has components $F_{\mu\nu}$ and with some effort you can show that
$$
F_{0i}~=~\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial t}~-~\frac{\partial A_0}{\partial x^i}~=~E_i
$$
$$
F_{ij}~=~\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x_j}~-~\frac{\partial A_j}{\partial x^i}~\rightarrow~B_i~=~-(\nabla\times A)_i.
$$
These are standard electromagnetic calculations. This would all be very different if there were the nonlinear terms $A\wedge A$ included. So classical electromagnetism is abelian.

Comment: But is the symmetry still $U(1)$, or something like $\mathbb{R}$? After all, there are no complex numbers around, all that changes is the potential.

Comment: Sigh! that is really a non-issue. Abelian symmetry is $U(1)$ and the $\pm 1$ weights correspond to the $\pm e$ charges.  Further, classical solutions can have $exp(-ikx + i\omega t)$ terms.

Comment: I think @Javier's worried about the topology of the group: $U(1)$ is not quite all of Abelian symmetry: its universal cover is $(\mathbb{R}, +)$. Of course they are the same at the algebra level: I'm getting the feeling that both the OP and Javier really want to know how the compactness of the symmetry group  arises and what role it plays.

Comment: @LawrenceB.Crowell The 'form notation' I'm not comfortable with. Can you be a little liberal and add an answer without using them (if possible)?

Comment: @LawrenceB.Crowell a good overview, but it doesn't fully answer the question of $ℝ$ vs U(1), since $ℝ$ is also Abelian and $A ∧ A$ would still be 0 if the group were $ℝ$ rather than U(1).