# A question about gauge transformations in classical electrodynamics and gauge transformations

Tags: group-theory, classical-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations, gauge-invariance, classical-field-theory

Consider the free Maxwell's equations without being coupled to matter fields, for simplicity. The equations are invariant under $$A_\mu(x)\to A_\mu(x)+\partial_\mu\chi(x)\tag{1}$$ where $\chi(x)$ is an arbitrary real-valued function.

(i) $\chi(x)$ lives on the vector space $\mathbb{R}$.

(ii) Moreover, the set of all $\chi(x)$ also form the elements of a continuous abelian group $(\mathbb{R},+)$ under addition. This conclusion has nothing to do with the transformation (1) but follows from the reality of the $A_\mu$ field.

**Question:** Is it the same $(\mathbb{R},+)$ group that I explained here is referred to the answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/352649/does-classical-electrodynamics-have-u1-symmetry-if-yes-how)? If yes, then what is U(1) ambiguity here? I think I'm confusing something because it's not $\chi(x)$ that becomes U(1) group element but it becomes the parameter of the U(1) group with a generic element $e^{i\chi(x)}$.

Comment: There is no reason to put the „i” in the exponential, it is only convenient to have it there when one moves to quantum mechanics/QFT. It is only in that context, that one has involution-algebra valued fields which couple to $A_{\mu}$, one speaks of the former's U(1) gauge invariance. But only within the context of a (co-)vector field on spacetime subject to your (1), there's no U(1) anywhere.